# Printing an array when not every cell is filled

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I am trying to populate an array with at least 12 doubles, then print the doubles in the array. If I use exactly 12 doubles, this works fine, but if I use fewer than 12 doubles, the program won't continue until I input 12. The code looks like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
int main(){
    double arr[12];
    printf("Enter Numbers\n");
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
        scanf_s("%lf",&arr[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
        printf("%f\n",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a simple change I can make so that if I input for instance the numbers 1 13 52 or the numbers 8 99 11 45 82, it will print them back to me? I am not worried about going over 12, and I don't care about wasted memory cells in the array.

Comment: You should care about adding more than 12 as this will result in undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you must have some exit condition. You can stop for example, when you input a negative number

```
int n = 12;
for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
    scanf_s("%lf",&arr[i]);
    if (arr[i] < 0) {
        n = i;
        break;
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%f\n",arr[i]);
}
```

Or some other condition, like inputting zero or some large negative number.

*Update:*

If you want to stop when there are no more numbers, you can check the return value of [`scanf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) as @leeduhem suggested

```
int n = 12;
for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
    int rc = scanf_s("%lf",&arr[i]);
    if (rc == 0 || rc == EOF) {
        n = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I guess I need it to break when it finishes reading the doubles that I input, even if I have not input 12 doubles. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you want to input 12 numbers regardless, you can leave out the `break` statement. This will mark the negative number position and still read all 12 doubles. But then, you must also make sure, there's no other negative number. Otherwise, `n` will point to the second or third one.

Comment: @user3342994 Yes, `break` if `scanf_s(..)` returns `EOF`.

Comment: Ok, I am not worried about negative numbers at all, though. Say for instance that I input "1 2 3 4 5". The loop will wait for me to input 7 more doubles before moving on. I don't want it to do that. I would just want it to populate arr[0]=1 arr[1]=2 arr[2]=3 arr[3]=4 arr[4]=5, and leave the rest of the cells blank, then print the contents of the array.

Comment: @leeduhem, your answer seems to be what I am looking for, but what would be the code to implement that?

Comment: @user3342994 Seems, I misunderstood your question. See updated answer.

Comment: Olaf Dietsche, This looks like it should work, but it still isn't for me. I changed my code, but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: @user3342994 Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    double arr[12];
    printf("Enter Numbers: \n");

    n = 0;
    while (scanf(" %lf", &arr[n++]) != EOF && n < 12)
        ;

    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        printf("%f\n",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run (Only tested on Linux):

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter Numbers: 
1 2 3
<=============== Ctr-D on Unix-like, Ctrl-Z on Windows
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
$ ./a.out 
Enter Numbers: 
1 2 3
4 5 6
<=============== Ctr-D on Unix-like, Ctrl-Z on Windows
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
5.000000
6.000000
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you posted and still have the same problem. I had to enter exactly 12 doubles to continue for some reason. Also, when i did it your way, the console only printed the first 11 doubles that i entered.

Comment: @user3342994 Only printed the first 11 doubles because after that `while` loop, `n` suppose to be 13, to I use `for (...; i < n - 1; ...)`. But in your case, some how, after `while` the value of `n` is 12.

Comment: @user3342994 How do you input your data? Have you tried my input data, e.g. '1 2 3', <enter>, <ctrl-d>.

Comment: Ok, when i try Ctrl-Z after inputting my data, it does print the numbers that I entered, but then it prints a few lines of long, random, numbers. Also, is there a way to do this without ctrl-z?

Comment: @user3342994 Extra random numbers? Somehow `n` gets a wrong value again. Without Ctrl-Z or Ctrl-D, how are you going to indicate the end of your input?